# How to detect different data types inside HTML page?

Tags: java, html, dom, web-crawler

What is the best way to detect data types inside html page using Java facilities DOM API, regexp, etc?
I'd like to detect types like skype plugin does for the phone/skype numbers, similar for addresses, emails, time, etc.

Comment: If you want relevant answer, you need to give more details of the problem.  Are these arbitrary web pages, or specific ones that you know the structure of?  Are they well-formed?  Are the values in well-known places in the pages or anywhere?  Do you care if they are visible to the user?  Is this a web crawling problem, ot are you trying to do this in a browser plugin? And generally, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hey Stephen,
This is generic html page with different structure, tables, lists, design elements, etc.
I'd like to validate only visible to users elements.
This is testing problem, blackbox. Crawling probably would be a best option but I can consider browser plugin as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Types' is an inappropriate term for the kind of information you are referring to. Choice of DOM API or regex depends upon the structure of information within the page.

If you know the structure, (for example tables being used for displaying information, you already know from which cell you can find phone number and which cell you can find email address), it makes sense to go with a DOM API.

Otherwise, you should use regex on plain HTML text without parsing it.

Comment: Doesn't the DOM API go berserk if it doesn't find a matching close tag? You can't expect all pages to be well-formed.

Comment: @user that depends upon what API implementation you are using. There are many such mature implementations that cater un-well-formed pages nicely. I have had very good experience with cobra parser: http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regexes in the following order:

1. Extract only the BODY content
2. Remove all tags to leave just plain text
3. Match relevant patterns in text

Of course, this assumes that markup isn't providing hints, and that you're purely extracting data, not modifying page context.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: Hey Phil, 
That realy to much work. Moreover one of the problem is to find relevant types 'cause some of them are very similar, like currency, number and phone number, which makes regexp usage very complex